Quantum phase estimation algorithm on a superposition of eigenstates
Given a Hamiltonian $H$ and a state $|\psi\rangle = c_1|E_0\rangle + c_2|E_1\rangle + \cdots$, with $|E_i\rangle$ being an eigenstate of $H$.
Can I use the QPE algorithm for $U|\psi\rangle= e^{-iHt}|\psi\rangle$ to estimate a random eigenvalue of $H$? Or rather, the bits of information may come from different eigenvalues, ending into a meaningless result?
What about Iterative Phase Estimation?

Say if you have a superposition state $|\phi\rangle$, of eigenstates of $U$, $\{|E_i\rangle \}$, such that   $$|\phi\rangle = \sum_i c_i |E_i\rangle\,,$$
and you perform the QPE starting with $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}|\phi\rangle$, then
$$|0\rangle^{\otimes n}|\phi\rangle \overset{\text{QPE}}{\rightarrow} \sum_i c_i|\lambda_i\rangle|E_i\rangle\,.$$
The result in the first register will be a superposition of all eigenvalues of $\{|E_i\rangle \}$ and measuring the first register in $Z$ basis would give you a particular eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ as a bitstring of length $n$, with probability $|c_k|^2$, and the second register will also collapse into eigenstate corresponding to $\lambda_k,$ $|E_k\rangle$.
Now, if you want to estimate eigenvalues of $H$ in a similar fashion, there is an issue. When you go from $H$ to $U =e^{-iHt}$, there is a loss of information. Eigenvalues of $H$ lies between $(-\infty, \infty)$, whereas eigenvalues of $U$ lies between $[-1, 1]$.
If you have a bound on eigenvalues of $H$, say they only lie in $(0, 2\pi]$ (or any interval of the real line of length $2\pi$), then doing QPE and getting a random eigenvalue of $H$ using superposition of eigenstates would be possible.

Thanks for pointing that out. Hence QPE only works within such limits? Or I may define the unitary to reduce the loss of information?

What do you mean by defining the unitary to reduce the loss of information?
